# Modal con imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css

muy buenas tardes.

El motivo por el que les escribo compañeros es para pedir de su apoyo estoy realizando una pagina web en la cual tengo unas imagenes que quiero que se hagan en una ventana modal al hacer click o pulsar sobre ella, el detalle es que logre hacer esa parte en una imagen si selecciono la otra imagen como que la anterio se sobrepone y tengo que dar dos click para quitar y despues otro ya para cerrar la ventana modal, no se que pueda estar fallando en mi codigo si me pueden apoyar por favor

codigo de html

```
<div class="imagenes">
                <div class="modal-container rounded-lg shadow-xl">
                    <img class="one" src="./img/1.png" alt="Foto1">
                    <p class="cer_text">FOTO 1</p>                    
                </div>

                <div class="modal-containerf rounded-lg shadow-xl">
                    <img class="two" src="./img/2.png" alt="Foto2">
                    <p class="cer_text">FOTO 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

codigo css

```
.modal-container.active{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.modal-container .one{
    z-index: 1;
}


.modal-container.active::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(47, 105, 130, 0.81);
    z-index: 0;
}



/*------------------------------*/
.modal-containerf.active{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.modal-containerf .two{
    z-index: 1;
}


.modal-containerf.active::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(47, 105, 130, 0.81);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

codigo js

```
const er = document.querySelector('.modal-container .one')
er.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
});


const et = document.querySelector('.modal-container')
et.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.remove('active');
});



const el = document.querySelector('.modal-containerf .two')
el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
});


const ek = document.querySelector('.modal-containerf')
ek.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.remove('active');
});
```